# Does JSON.parse work for deep / nested objects?

Tags: javascript, json

For example if we have:

```
let r = JSON.parse('{"o": {"name": "foo","lastName": "boo"}}');
```

Can we now do `console.log(r.o.name);` and get `foo` on the console?

Comment: Have you *tried* it? BTW `JSON.parse` takes a stringified JSON object

Comment: Did you try it and get something you didn’t expect?

Comment: What happened when you tried this to make you ask this question?

Comment: The question’s not really obvious, since you still have an object, not JSON. It doesn’t make sense to parse it.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a problem statement, hence the closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Here's a runnable example:

```js
let r = JSON.parse('{"o": {"name": "foo","lastName": "boo"}}');
console.log(r.o.name)
```

Comment: How would you parse '{"o": "{"name": "foo","lastName": "boo"}"}' ?

Comment: @MayankMehtani . where did you get this from ? its not proper json format. Check your json on https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html